# VueJS and Webpack: Unit Testing error -- do I need the default HelloWorld component?

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, vuejs2

I am using vue-cli with webpack for the first time and trying out the unit testing feature. However, I deleted the default HelloWorld.vue component because I didn't need that in my custom app. So, when running the following command in terminal I get a unit testing error:

```js
$ npm run test

> vuetemplate@1.0.0 test D:\Users\myName\Desktop\vue-cli-webpacktemplate
> npm run unit


> vuetemplate@1.0.0 unit D:\Users\myName\Desktop\vue-cli-webpacktemplate
> jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage

 FAIL  test\unit\specs\HelloWorld.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:

    Could not locate module @/components/HelloWorld (mapped as D:\Users\myName\Desktop\vue-cli-webpacktemplate\src\components/HelloWorld)

    Please check:

    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "/^@\/(.*)$/": "D:\Users\myName\Desktop\vue-cli-webpacktemplate\src\$1"
    },
    "resolver": undefined

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
```

My question: I'd like to do unit testing on my app. Do I need to put that default HelloWorld component back in order to successfully do testing on my app? Or, is there a way to skip it? Not sure what to do here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is not referenced as an import on your AppComponent or any other component. Maybe on the tests.

Comment: It's reference din the tests folder under the 'specs' folder like so: `import Vue from 'vue'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld', i need to find out where in the folder structure it's referencing this path so i can turn it off or something

Comment: You can simply use a "find in all files" from most text editors to find this import statement. IIRC, it would be located on test/unit/specs/HelloComponent.spec.js or something